# Retrieving list from Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is my Database structure]

I want retrieve movie name that type is action.I use this query but it didn't work.

```
  Query query = mRef.child("Movie").orderByChild("1").equalTo("Action");
```

How can I retrieve movie name that type is action?

Comment: add the data structure, so we could understand how you are saving data in the database.

Comment: You're using an array to model what is essentially a set. There are many reasons to not use arrays in Firebase and this is one of them. For one way to model this type of relation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Answer (score 0):

Action is under type node, so modify your query.

```
Query query = mRef.child("Movie").orderByChild("1").child("Type").equalTo("Action");
```